# SIGSEGV in CUDA allocation

Tags: c++, cuda, segmentation-fault

I've an host array of `uint64_t` of size `spectrum_size` and I need to allocate and copy it on my GPU.
But when I'm trying to allocate this in the GPU memory, but I continue to receive SIGSEGV... Any ideas?

```
   uint64_t * gpu_hashed_spectrum;
   uint64_t * gpu_hashed_spectrum_h = new uint64_t [spectrum_size];
   HANDLE_ERROR(cudaMalloc((void **)&gpu_hashed_spectrum, sizeof(uint64_t *) * spectrum_size));
   for(i=0; i<spectrum_size; i++) {
      HANDLE_ERROR(cudaMalloc((void **)&gpu_hashed_spectrum_h[i], sizeof(uint64_t)));
   }
   printf("\t\t...Copying\n");
   for(i=0; i<spectrum_size; i++) {
      HANDLE_ERROR(cudaMemcpy((void *)gpu_hashed_spectrum_h[i], (const void *)hashed_spectrum[i], sizeof(uint64_t), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));
   }
   HANDLE_ERROR(cudaMemcpy(gpu_hashed_spectrum, gpu_hashed_spectrum_h, spectrum_size * sizeof(uint64_t *), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));
```

Full code available [here](https://github.com/Cordaz/AAPPproject/blob/master/cuda_main.cu)

UPDATE:

I tried to do in this way, noy I've got SIGSEGV on other parts of the code (in the kernel, when using this array. Maybe is due to other errors.

```
   uint64_t * gpu_hashed_spectrum;
   HANDLE_ERROR(cudaMalloc((void **)&gpu_hashed_spectrum, sizeof(uint64_t) * spectrum_size));
   HANDLE_ERROR(cudaMemcpy(gpu_hashed_spectrum, hashed_spectrum, spectrum_size * sizeof(uint64_t), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));
```

Comment: Seriously, I gave you a complete working example of how to do this in an answer to your last question. Give me a good reason why I should just close this as a duplicate of your question from yesterday?

Comment: It's not the same problem, the example of yesterday actually works well, the problem here is not in the allocation, but hte fact that this make a SIGSEGV... I didn't understand very well... I'm very sorry... I made this on the idea of the yesterday example

Comment: I can't even figure out what you are trying to do.  It seems fairly clear that you intend `gpu_hashed_spectrum` to be a pointer-to-a-pointer, because you are allocating space for `uint64_t *` (and it kind of looks like you are trying to do a deep copy...) but why have you declared it as a single pointer?  And are you in fact trying to do a deep copy where each single pointer is pointing to only *one* data item, as your looped `cudaMemcpy` operation is suggesting (`sizeof(uint64_t)`).  Why would you do that?

Comment: I can certainly tell you which line is generating the seg fault (and why), but probably you can figure that out too.  It might help if you write a question that explains your intent ("I have this data structure on the host, I would like to be able to move it and access it on the device in the same way....")

Comment: I'm trying to allocate an array of `uint64_t` and copy the value stored in my host array `hashed_spectrum` in it.

Comment: That can be done with a single `cudaMemcpy` operation, using a single pointer on the host and a single pointer on the device.  Take a look at the CUDA `vectorAdd` sample code.

Comment: What you have now shown in your edited question should work just fine for copying a flat array.  If that's not working, the problem is most likely in something you haven't shown.  You should provide a [mcve].

Comment: I added the full code link, provide a minimal example it's quite complex right now... I also found the error. It happen when I'm copy back a string array: `HANDLE_ERROR(cudaMemcpy(reads, gpu_reads, sizeof(char) * (READS_LENGTH + 1) * inputDim, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));`
I'm tryng to figure out now.

Comment: A link to your project on an external web site with 400+ loc is not a [mcve].  Perhaps you should actually read that link.  SO expects this example to be provided *in the question itself*.  Read [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) "Questions seeking debugging help...."

Answer (score 1):

At least you are confused about `uint64_t**` and `unit64_t*`.

At line 1, you define `gpu_hashed_spectrum` as a pointer, pointing to some data of the type `unit64_t`, but at line 3

```
HANDLE_ERROR(cudaMalloc((void **)&gpu_hashed_spectrum, sizeof(uint64_t *) * spectrum_size));
```

you use `gpu_hashed_spectrum` as a pointer, pointing to some data of the type `unit64_t*`.

Maybe you should change your definition to

```
uint64_t** gpu_hashed_spectrum;
```

As well as some other lines.